# Unable to import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse Kepler. When I try to use `java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch` it is showing error that unable to import. I don't know how to check if this class is present in Java libraries or not. Maybe because this class is not present , Eclipse is not able to import this class.
Please tell me how to check the presence of this library. And if not present how to add the class to existing library.

I have rectified the error and following is the working code. I have replaced every CountDownLatch with java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch. Hence now I don't need to import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch package at all.
But I want to understand why eclipse was not able to import this package.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class Runner4 implements Runnable {
    private java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch latch;
    private int i;

    public Runner4(java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch latch, int i) {
        this.latch = latch;
        this.i = i;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("In thread " + i);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        latch.countDown();
    }
}

public class CountDownLatch {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch latch = new java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch(
                1);

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
            executor.submit(new Runner4(latch, i));

        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Thank-you

Comment: Post the full and exact error message. Then check for a valid JRE in your build path.

Comment: `java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch` is available from Java 1.5. So the question is which version do you use?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis exact error is:The import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch can not be resolved. And java version is 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

Press **Ctrl+Shift+T** in eclipse window. Type the class name "CountDownLatch". If its present in your workspace it will show, if not upgrade your Java version.

Comment: I am using Java 7. And java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch is from java 5.